# Why does the space-evenly property does not exist in align-content?

Tags: css, flexbox

Why does the space-evenly property does not exist in align-content?

The space-evenly property exist for justify-content. Why not for align-content?

Comment: Do you have an example showing it doesn't work for you ? Could be anything, a typo, no height specified, misuse of grid or flex, wrong selector chosen, etc. Clarify your question because as answered below, it does exists :) or there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content

Answer (score 0):

The `space-evenly` value exist in `align-content property`.